# Can't use boost::stream with std::string<unsigned char> to instanciate boost::binary_oarchive or boost::binary_iarchive

Tags: c++, boost, stream, boost-serialization, unsigned-char

Cheer developer,

i have got trouble with the next code (visual studio 2015 compiler):

```
template<typename SERIALIZABLE_TYPE, typename BUFFER_TYPE>
inline void Serialize::IntoStringBuffer(const SERIALIZABLE_TYPE& object, BUFFER_TYPE& strBuffer)
{
    back_insert_device<BUFFER_TYPE> inserter(strBuffer);
    stream<back_insert_device<BUFFER_TYPE>> aStream(inserter);

    binary_oarchive binaryOutArchive(aStream);
    binaryOutArchive & object;

    aStream.flush();
}

template<typename SERIALIZABLE_TYPE, typename BUFFER_TYPE>
inline void Types::Serialize::FromStringBuffer(const BUFFER_TYPE& strBuffer, SERIALIZABLE_TYPE& object)
{
    basic_array_source<typename BUFFER_TYPE::value_type> arraySource(strBuffer.data(), strBuffer.size());
    stream<basic_array_source<typename BUFFER_TYPE::value_type>> aStream(arraySource);

    binary_iarchive binaryInArchive(aStream);
    binaryInArchive & object;
}
```

When i use these helpers with a serialize object and a std::string buffer, the solution build.

However, i have to use std::basic_string with unsigned char type as buffer. Then, the solution doesn't compile anymore:

```
error C2664: 'boost::archive::binary_iarchive::binary_iarchive(const boost::archive::binary_iarchive &)' : impossible de convertir l'argument 1 de 'boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<unsigned char>,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' en 'std::istream &' with[_Elem=unsigned char,_Ty=unsigned char]
```

and

```
error C2664: 'boost::archive::binary_oarchive::binary_oarchive(const boost::archive::binary_oarchive &)' : impossible de convertir l'argument 1 de 'boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<BUFFER_TYPE>,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' en 'std::ostream &' with [ BUFFER_TYPE=std::basic_string<unsigned char>, _Elem=unsigned char, _Ty=unsigned char]
```

I wasn't able to determine which is exactly the problem ? and how to solve it ?

Some advises ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that unsigned character streams are not supported.

Neither is there any need for this. Things are binary anyways. Any stream buffer in `std::ios::binary` mode will do.